# React-Router - what is ga?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to read up on React `useLocation` to figure out how to get the historical navigation of my pages.

[The documentation sample](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation) shows the use of something called "ga". I am not sure what is it supposed to be or what is it imported from. When I tried to copy it directly into my code with the assumption its something built-in, I get

```
'ga' is not defined  no-undef
```

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  let location = useLocation();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }, [location]);

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

I am running on the theory it's supposed to be **G**oogle **A**nalytics, but most sample codes I've seen import it as `ReactGA`.

Comment: it is google analytics, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs

Comment: Weird, not really. Useful... also not really. It's likely just google analytics, and is only used as an example of using the location when issuing a side-effect like updating page views.